# Update/refresh notebook variable color on clear

Tags: front-end, contexts, syntax-highlighting

By default, *Mathematica* displays variable names already assigned as black while new variables are displayed in blue. When executing `` Clear["Global`*"] ``, variables that's already assigned will change from black to blue. However, if done via a `Button`:

```
CreatePalette[Button["Clear", Clear["Global`*"] ] ]
```

the variables will be cleared but their color will not be changed to blue, which looks confusing to me. How to remedy that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was digging around one day and I found appropriate function for this.

`` FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`Private`GetUpdatedSymbolContexts[]; `` will help if you read a package or clear symbols from different place than the notebook interface.

```
CreatePalette[
 Button["Clear", 
   Clear["Global`*"]; 
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`Private`GetUpdatedSymbolContexts[];
   ,
   ImageSize -> 100,
   Method    -> "Queued"

 ]
]
```

Keep in mind that it is undocumented so who knows what may happen :)

Comment: Works like a charm for me :-) Thanks! (tested on Mathematica ver. 10.0.2.0 on windows)

Comment: @egwenesedai By default Button is not queued so it may fail for more complex procedures by evaluating it prematurely. But it should be enough to use `Method->"Queued"`. Depends of your needs and context ofc. Good luck.